# NSMutableArray accessing data

Tags: iphone, sdk, nsmutablearray

Is it possible to get the tag of a random button in an Array?

```
- (IBAction)actionButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random()% [_allButtons count];
    NSLog(@"%d", randomIndex);
    NSLog(@"tag: %@",[_allButtons objectAtIndex:randomIndex]);
}
```

From the log I get this:

```
UIRoundedRectButton:.... frame = (110 98; 50 44); opaque = NO; **tag = 5**; layer = CALayer.....
```

Is it possible to just get the tag from the random button?

EDIT: sorry _allButtons is an NSMutableArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-

```
(IBAction) actionButtonPressed:(id)sender {

    NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random()% [_allButtons count];

    NSLog(@"%d", randomIndex);

    NSLog(@"tag: %d", [[_allButtons objectAtIndex:randomIndex] tag]);

}
```